# Fetch from mySQL to HTML TABLE

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have used this code but its not fetching anything other than displaying the table on the web.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>database connections</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
      $username = "root";
      $password = " ";
      $host = "localhost";

      $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
          or die("Unable to connect");
        echo "Connections are made successfully::";
      $selected = mysql_select_db("ticad", $connector)
        or die("Unable to connect");

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ");

      ?>
      <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Names</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Event</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
            echo
            "<tr>
              <td>{$row\['id'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['Names'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['Company'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['Position'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['Email'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['Event'\]}</td> 
              <td>{$row\['Comments'\]}</td> 
            </tr>\n";
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
     <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[This is my Table and dabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk0ci.png)

[This is what am getting when I run the code as a web. I want all the records to be displayed on the table as we fetch from the table users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zovj.png)

Comment: PHP is usually not executed in .html files, and it is for sure not executed when you don’t even view the files via HTTP over a local webserver, but use the file protocol instead. So the first thing you should do is go read up on how to set up a local development environment to test PHP pages.

Comment: @user3671937 Are you running this on a local server (like XAMPP) or just opening it like a normal HTML file? Also remove the '\' characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and don't escape... And as I saw your picture. You need to upload your file onto webserver with support of PHP. Rename your file to .php extension

```
  echo
        "<tr>
          <td>".$row['id']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Names']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Company']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Position']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Email']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Event']."</td> 
          <td>".$row['Comments']."</td> 
        </tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the brackets:

```
<td>{$row['id']}</td>
```

Comment: I have change to ..but still the same thing.  
<td>{$row['id']}</td>
     
<td>{$row['Names']}</td>
     
<td>{$row['Company']}</td>
     
<td>{$row['Position']}</td>
     
<td>{$row['Email']}</td>
     
<td>{$row['Comments']}</td>

Comment: Oh, the problem is that you need to run this on a webserver. Don't just open it as an HTML file.